# В строке браузера после ввода домен меняется на IP

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, redirect, vps, веб-служба

Имеется:

1. VPS с установленной Ubuntu 14
2. Spring MVC приложение запущенное на Tomcat на данном сервере
3. Приложение можно посмотреть здесь (еще много чего надо допиливать): http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8080
4. Доменное имя http://myDomainName.pp.ua
5. Переадресация (или как оно правильно называется?) этого домена на IP на сайте https://nic.ua/ (скрин ниже)

Так вот, при вводе в строку браузера http://myDomainName.pp.ua мы переходим на http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8080 однако и в самой строке мы теперь видим http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8080. Что сделать чтобы в строке браузера оставалось доменное имя (также и после перехода по страницам приложения: напр. /home, /setting дописывалось к домену)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас стоит обычный редирект у домена, вам необходимо привязать домен к IP-адресу VPS и возможно донастроить TomCat

Comment: как это сделать?